# How to format time in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my winforms app, I have to display time in hh:mm format (04:30 PM).
How to convert it into this format?

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm tt";
```

Comment: That line of code you have here should work. Can you explain if it isn't or what sort of problem you are encountering please?

Comment: This was the query that I used: string query 2 = "select chName, MassType, Date, Time, Stipend from SubList where chID= '" + Person.churchID.ToString() + "';";                      The error I received when I use that statement is: System.Format.Exception: Input string was not in a correct format. In the database time is a time(7) datatype.